# One to Many relationship -- Inserts 2 records into table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a one to many relationship: a Visitor has many Visits

Inside the Visitor model I have

```
public function visits()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Visit');
}
```

Inside the Visit model I have

```
public function visitor()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Visitor');
}
```

Inside my controller, I have a Visitor model and a Visit model. When I do

```
$visitor->visits()->save($visit);
```

I sometimes get 2 entries in the visits table. If I just set the visitor_id of the $visit object and then just call

```
$visit->save()
```

then it works, no problems. Is there a bug in Laravel 4 or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's a double click?

Comment: The browser makes the ajax call. For some reason, only "sometimes" the function is called twice. When I check the network tab, I only see one call ... so I'm not sure how to trace this

Comment: I would try to eliminate when and where this occurs. Remove any complexity (AJAX). If you can reproduce this problem, remove each part at a time and break down where it might be being called twice etc. Not sure what else to suggest without really getting hands on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried associating it:

```
$visitor->save();
$visit->visitor()->associate($visitor);
$visit->save();
```

Comment: uhm, i'm gettin Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()